# WPF Data binding: How to bind items in ItemsCollection to Grid.Row and Grid.Column?

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a class:

```
public class TempClass
{
    public int Row
    {
        get { return row; }
        set { row = value; }
    }
    public int Column
    {
        get { return column; }
        set { column = value; }
    }
    public string Value
    {
        get { return this.value; }
        set { this.value = value; }
    }

    int row;
    int column;
    string value;

    public TempClass(int row, int column, string value)
    {
        this.row = row;
        this.column = column;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

I have created a `List<TempClass> DummyCollection` and I have bound it to an `ItemsControl`. The `ItemsControl` uses a `UniformGrid` panel for `ItemsPanel` property. Here is the XAML code:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DummyCollection}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Rows="3" Columns="5" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="TempClass">
            <Border>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

I want to be able to bind `TempClass` items to the particular cell in the `ItemsControl`, i.e. I want to set the `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` properties of the item container to match `Row` and `Column` properties of the `TempClass` items. How do I achieve that? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding Row}"/>
            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding Column}"/>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    ...
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Thanks Kent. I've noticed that if, for instance, I have only one item in my `List<TempClass> DummyCollection` collection and that item has `Row=2` and `Column=3`, the item is placed in the beginning of the `UniformGrid`. Is that because all previous cells in the grid have width and height set to 0?

Comment: @Boris That is happening to me too! Looks like binding for Grid.Row and Grid.Column does not work.